# Millions of rows table optimization SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, ado.net, database-optimization

I have a table with millions of rows:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[RequestIdentities]
(
    [Id] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [UniqueKey] [nvarchar](256) NULL,
    [Timestamp] [datetime] NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_RequestIdentities] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
                    WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, 
                          IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, 
                          ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 80) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[RequestIdentities] 
    ADD CONSTRAINT [DF_RequestIdentities_Timestamp]  
        DEFAULT (GETDATE()) FOR [Timestamp]
GO
```

A Web API manipulates the database using ADO.NET and does:

1. Executes this query:

   ```
    SELECT 1 
    FROM RequestIdentities WITH (nolock) 
    WHERE UniqueKey = @key
   ```
2. If exists:

   ```
    if(reader.HasRows)
   ```
3. Returns a http response.
4. Otherwise, it inserts the id into the table:

   ```
    INSERT INTO RequestIdentities(UniqueKey) 
    VALUES(@key)
   ```

There are hundreds of inserts/updates every minutes, is there something I can do to optimize the table, like custom statistics/indexes?

Comment: That's small data and low traffic. Indexes are needed for *all* tables. `TOP 1` is meaningless as a unique key *guarantees* a single result. At best, it's a no-op, worst case it forces an extra operation. `WITH (NOLOCK)` is actually a horrible idea, resulting in dirty or duplicate results and *more* locks. You haven't provided any information about this table apart from the fact it has an ID, so it's impossible to say what, if anything, may need optimization

Comment: Have you encountered any actual problems? BTW if you want to retrieve only a single value use `ExecuteScalar` instead of `ExecuteReader`. If you want to avoid problems, avoid using long-lived connections and transactions. Connections and transactions accumulate locks, leading to blocking and delays. That's why common way of creating and using a connection is inside a `using` block.

Comment: BTW why `SELECT 1`? If you need to read any data for that row later on you'll have to execute another query. That's twice the latency and if you use transactions, longer-lived locks. If you want to insert something if it doesn't already exist, you can use `INSERT ... WHERE NOT EXISTS()` or `MERGE` to perform the operation in a single query.

Comment: BTW `UniqueKey` *needs* a UNIQUE index or constraint, otherwise it can't be unique

Comment: If you have really high traffic and enough memory, you can use in-memory tables to reduce latency and locking. Think of the table as a durable Redis cache in this case, only better.

Answer (score 1):

1M rows isn't a lot of data for a modern database on machines that use SSDs. A few hundreds of inserts aren't a lot either. While you can optimize this with eg in-memory tables, you have to remove the existing problems first.

In-memory tables can lead to simpler maintenance in some scenarios too.

**Problems**

This code contains several issues that *harm* performance.

- `WITH (NOLOCK)` is a very bad idea that *doesn't* improve performance at all. It actually takes *more extensive locks (schema-level), reads dirty, uncommitted data, can return the same data twice, and can even throw an error.
- The code executes two remote calls, resulting in twice the latency, to insert a single row. Apart from the delay, this means the locks acquired during the `SELECT` operation need to be held for far longer than needed, potentially blocking other connections that try to use the same table.
- TOP 1 is a no-op at best. If `UniqueKey` is really unique, only one result will be returned.

**Fix**

You can improve this by *removing* the hints and existence check. An `INSERT` query can include `FROM` and `WHERE` clause which means you can write a single query to only INSERT a new row. You can use the OUTPUT clause to return the ID of the new row.

First, you need to add either a UNIQUE index or constraint on the `UniqueKey` column. Without one of those, this simply isn't unique. Anyone can insert duplicate values. A UNIQUE constraint actually creates a UNIQUE index:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX IX_ RequestIdentities_UniqueKey   
   ON RequestIdentities (UniqueKey);
```

After that, you can conditionally insert and retrieve the new ID with :

```
INSERT INTO RequestIdentities (UniqueKey)
    OUTPUT inserted.ID
SELECT @key
FROM RequestIdentities
WHERE NOT EXISTS ( select * 
                   from RequestIdentities
                   where UniqueKey = @key)
```

The query optimizer knows it doesn't need to produce any results for `EXISTS ( SELECT *` so that doesn't affect performance.

This query will insert the new row and return the new ID. This operation is atomic (it either succeeds or rolls back) so there's no need for an explicit transaction.

You can execute this query through a SqlCommand by using `ExecuteScalar()`. This will return the new ID, or `null` if there are no results, because no row was inserted :

```
using(var connection=new SqlConnection(connString))
using(var cmd=new SqlCommand(query,connection))
{
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@key",SqlDbType.NVarChar,256).Value=key;
    connection.Open();
    var result = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
    if (result!=null)
    {
        var newID=(long)result;
        //Use the ID
        ...
    }
}
```

You can get fancy using C# 8's pattern matching syntax :

```
if(result is long newId)
{
   //Use the ID
}
```

If this code gets too much, you can use a micro-ORM like [Dapper](https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper) :

```
using(var connection=new SqlConnection(connString))
{
    var result=connection.ExecuteScalar(query,new {key=keyValue});
    if (result is long new ID)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

`Dapper` is used by StackOverflow so its performance is guaranteed.

**Other optimizations**

If you find there are too many locks with this table, a possible optimization is to use [memory optimized tables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/in-memory-oltp/introduction-to-memory-optimized-tables?view=sql-server-ver15). Database servers already buffer data aggressively.

The real benefit of a memory optimized table is the different logging, locking and access model. Instead of locks, lightweight in-memory latch objects are used. Since the data is already in memory, the server can use different operators and different types of indexes to retrieve and modify objects.

[This documentation example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/in-memory-oltp/creating-a-memory-optimized-table-and-a-natively-compiled-stored-procedure?view=sql-server-ver15) uses in-memory tables for two high-traffic tables:

- The Cart is a durable in-memory table, whose data is persisted to disk. If the server goes down, the carts are preserved.
- User sessions is a non-durable in-memory table. If the server goes down, we don't care about sessions

In this case, the table could be:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[RequestIdentities]
(
    [Id] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL 
        PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED,
    [UniqueKey] [nvarchar](256) NULL,
    [Timestamp] [datetime] NULL
)  
WITH (  
    MEMORY_OPTIMIZED = ON,  
    //Assuming we want to retain the data
    DURABILITY = SCHEMA_AND_DATA);  
go  

ALTER TABLE RequestIdentities  
    ADD CONSTRAINT RequestIdentities_UniqueKey  
    UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED (UniqueKey);  
go
```

Comment: Let's add to this one more optimization. Maybe "correction" is a better term. The actual data columns should NOT be nullable. Currently all of those are nullable which is logical nonsense.

Comment: @SMor there's a lot of information missing from the question.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos . . . To be honest, a few million rows and a few hundred inserts per minute wasn't such a big deal twenty years ago before SSDs and on slower machines.

Comment: @GordonLinoff given how many SO questions there are about big data and 50K-row tables, this needs repeating every time.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a column containing the `hash` value of the field you are searching.

First, add new column to the table:

```
ALTER TABLE [...]
ADD [UniqueKeyHash] VARBINARY(64);
```

Then, add index on it:

```
CREATE INDEX IX_..._UniqueKeyHash ON [...]
(
    [UniqueKeyHash] 
);
```

Populate the values:

```
UPDATE [...]
SET [UniqueKeyHash] =  HASHBYTES('SHA2_512', UniqueKey);
```

Modify the CRUD routines to calculate the `HASH`, too.

Then, in search:

```
DECLARE @UniqueKeyHash VARBINARY(64);

SET @UniqueKeyHash = HASHBYTES('SHA2_512', 'some value');

SELECT *
FROM [...]
WHERE [UniqueKeyHas] = @UniqueKeyHash;
```

Alternatively, you can add the column as `computed and persisted` in order to skip modifying the `CRUD` routines.

I am using such search on various places - one of it is in a IP Addresses table from which  is search on each user log in and contains millions of records.

If this is too hard for you, you can start with creating an index on the `UniqueKey`.

Comment: Why do this? The problem is the two remote queries, the lack of indexing and `NOLOCK`. Without a UNIQUE index, `UniqueKey` can't be unique so that index is needed anyway

Comment: Were you thinking of in-memory tables perhaps?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos No, as I said finding a string even having a unique index might be slow. In my case, the query took 1-2 seconds which is too much when a user is logging in the system. Adding a `hash` column and index solve the issue.

Comment: An indexed hash column is no different from an indexed string column, apart from the IO overhead. Which can be handled more efficiently by compression. This would exchange scarce IO resources for the more plentiful CPU resources. In a login scenario, the time needed to calculate the password hash will be more than 1".

Comment: Of course there is a difference :-) and in my case it was 2 seconds. Also, note I am talking about IP address which is short string ... imaging something bigger. I can't see how compression will work in such case - it's a slower variant and overkill for such task.

Answer (score 0):

1. A FILLFACTOR = 80 on a very big table an especially on a CLUSTERED IDENTITY INDEX is a nonsense. You loose 20 % of space !
2. if UniqueKey column is UNIQUE, add a UNIQUE constraint.
3. [Timestamp] is a reserved word, don't use it as a column name.

After having do this job, you can use the following query :

```
INSERT INTO dbo.RequestIdentities(UniqueKey)
OUTPUT inserted.* INTO ...
SELECT @key
EXCEPT
SELECT UniqueKey
FROM   dbo.RequestIdentities
WHERE  UniqueKey = @Key;
```

Aand returns the OUTPUT result clause into a table to your client application